# Query is not working accordingly in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Select sum(num) as num, sum(numbr) as numbr
from
(
    (Select 0 as num)
    union all
    (Select 1 as num)
) t, 
(
    (Select 2 as numbr)
    union all
    (Select 3 as numbr)
) t1
```

giving result:

```
num numbr
2   10
```

But the correct result should be

```
num numbr
1   5
```

Comment: if you use union the name of the column doesn't matter it's the order

Comment: The query is working as expected. There is a `CROSS JOIN` there, so rows from each table as duplicated. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Giorgos I am not aware that the Cross Join is happening in it.. Thanks for telling...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the cross product of a table containing 0 and 1, and a table containing 2 and 3. Try removing the sums:

```
Select num, numbr as numbr from 
(
(Select 0 as num)
union all
(Select 1 as num))t, 
((Select 2 as numbr)
union all
(Select 3 as numbr)
)t1
```

This gives you:

```
0;2
0;3
1;2
1;3
```

Which will correctly sum to 2 and 10.

Comment: Thanks @small_duck

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you are `CROSS JOINING` , every record connect to every record with out a relation condition, which means that in this case, your join becomes this:

```
NUM | NUMBR
 0      2
 0      3
 1      2  
 1      3
```

Which `SUM(NUM)` = 2 and `SUM(NUMBR)` = 10 .

When joining, you have to specify the relation condition unless this is what you want.

Note: You are using implicit join syntax(comma separated) , you should avoid that and use the explicit syntax and this will help you make sure you are using a relation condition (by the `ON` clause):

```
Select sum(num) as num, sum(numbr) as numbr
from
(
    (Select 0 as num)
    union all
    (Select 1 as num)
) t
INNER JOIN 
(
    (Select 2 as numbr)
    union all
    (Select 3 as numbr)
) t1
ON(t.<Col> = t1.<Col1>)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select num, numbr as numbr
from
(
    (Select 0 as num)
    union all
    (Select 1 as num)
) t, 
(
    (Select 2 as numbr)
    union all
    (Select 3 as numbr)
) t1
```

Gives you the cartessian product of tables.

```
| Num | Number |
|-----|--------|
| 0   | 2      |
| 0   | 3      |
| 1   | 2      |
| 1   | 3      |
```

Therefore the sum of these are 2 and 10

Answer (score 1):

Its correctly working as you wrote. If you want the result as you expected, try this:

```
Select sum(distinct num) as num, sum(distinct numbr) as numbr
from
(
(Select 0 as num)
union all
(Select 1 as num)
) t, 
(
(Select 2 as numbr)
union all
(Select 3 as numbr)
) t1
```